# Vagrant box add - Failed to connect to cloud-images.ubuntu.com port 443: Timed out

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

I'm new to Vagrant. Using this vagrant add box command:

```
vagrant add box ubuntu/trusty64
```

to add this box [ubuntu/trusty64](https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64), I'm getting this error:

> An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
>   message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
>   again.
>
> Failed to connect to cloud-images.ubuntu.com port 443: Timed out

Reinstalling Vagrant didn't work.

`vagrant -version` output: *Vagrant 2.1.4*

`OS`: *Windows 10 Enterprise*

Comment: Can you actually access the site from your PC / via ping?

Comment: @maio290 yes I can.

Comment: I see this happen with Hashi software when the DNS usage on the device is misconfigured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) fixed it for me. To be on safe side I removed Vagrant, Git Bash and VirtualBox and all references. Reinstalled all of these using default settings. Issue doesn't occur anymore.

Answer (score 0):

first initialize the vagrant

```
$ vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
$ vagrant up
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Unfortunately I'm still getting same error.